# Calendar Date dot under date text, How to Remove?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]    [calendar_date_picker2: ^0.5.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPqP9.png)

Using this library I want to hide a dot below the date text

Comment: I don't see any dot using it with default values. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using [calendar_date_picker2:^0.5.3](https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_date_picker2) package. If yes, please find the CalendarDatePicker2WithActionButtonsConfig function in the code below.

```
_buildCalendarDialogButton() {
    const dayTextStyle =
        TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700);
    final weekendTextStyle =
        TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500], fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);
    final anniversaryTextStyle = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red[400],
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
    );
    final config = CalendarDatePicker2WithActionButtonsConfig(
      dayTextStyle: dayTextStyle,
      calendarType: CalendarDatePicker2Type.range,
      selectedDayHighlightColor: Colors.purple[800],
      closeDialogOnCancelTapped: true,
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,

      weekdayLabelTextStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black87,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      controlsTextStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      centerAlignModePicker: true,
      customModePickerIcon: const SizedBox(),
      selectedDayTextStyle: dayTextStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
      dayTextStylePredicate: ({required date}) {
        TextStyle? textStyle;
        if (date.weekday == DateTime.saturday ||
            date.weekday == DateTime.sunday) {
          textStyle = weekendTextStyle;
        }
        if (DateUtils.isSameDay(date, DateTime(2021, 1, 25))) {
          textStyle = anniversaryTextStyle;
        }
        return textStyle;
      },
      dayBuilder: ({
        required date,
        textStyle,
        decoration,
        isSelected,
        isDisabled,
        isToday,
      }) {
        Widget? dayWidget;
        if (date.day % 3 == 0 && date.day % 9 != 0) {
          dayWidget = Container(
            decoration: decoration,
            child: Center(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    MaterialLocalizations.of(context).formatDecimal(date.day),
                    style: textStyle,
                  ),
                  /*Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 27.5),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 4,
                      width: 4,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: isSelected == true
                            ? Colors.red
                            : Colors.grey[500],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),*/
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        return dayWidget;
      },
      yearBuilder: ({
        required year,
        decoration,
        isCurrentYear,
        isDisabled,
        isSelected,
        textStyle,
      }) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: decoration,
            height: 36,
            width: 72,
            child: Center(
              child: Semantics(
                selected: isSelected,
                button: true,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      year.toString(),
                      style: textStyle,
                    ),
                    if (isCurrentYear == true)
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final values = await showCalendarDatePicker2Dialog(
                context: context,
                config: config,
                dialogSize: const Size(325, 400),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                value: _dialogCalendarPickerValue,
                dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              );
              if (values != null) {
                // ignore: avoid_print
                print(_getValueText(
                  config.calendarType,
                  values,
                ));
                setState(() {
                  _dialogCalendarPickerValue = values;
                });
              }
            },
            child: const Text('Open Calendar Dialog'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now, all you need to do is **remove/comment the code below**, and that will eliminate the dot under the date text.

```
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 27.5),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 4,
                      width: 4,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: isSelected == true
                            ? Colors.red
                            : Colors.grey[500],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Please verify, I trust this should resolve your concern.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the code example from [here](https://github.com/theideasaler/calendar_date_picker2/blob/main/example/lib/main.dart). They added `dayBuilder` to showcase how you can customize the widget for certain days. To fix this, remove the `dayBuilder` from your config.

```dart
CalendarDatePicker2WithActionButtonsConfig(
...
dayBuilder: ..., // remove this
)
```